# HP LaserJet 1018 macOS Mojave and Catalina USB driver

Tags: macos, mojave, catalina, printing

it seems that HP abandoned old cheap, but very functional and small printers like HP LaserJet 1018.

Posting this question to share solution, that allows extend usability of normally functioning hardware, not to buy new unneeded one, save resources and planet.

Comment: Why do you phrase it like that: *HP Abandoned*. It’s an entry level, consumer grade printer released in 2009.  Are you expecting drivers to be written for it in perpetuity and somehow ending support is just a customer slap in the face?  Abandoned is when Apple decided to get rid of all ports and connectors after they literally promoted it the prior year and leaves you obsolete with a pirate’s booty of useless and expensive dongles.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

HP site says that no software or drivers found for your operating system when it comes to latest macOS versions.

Solution is to use HP printer driver bundle from file `HewlettPackardPrinterDrivers5.1.dmg` which can be found on
[Apple](https://support.apple.com/kb/DL1888?viewlocale=en_US&locale=en_US) or search engine or [direct link](http://support.apple.com/downloads/DL1888/en_US/HewlettPackardPrinterDrivers5.1.dmg)

- Download and install the printer driver package
- Open System Preferences -> Printers and Scanners
- Click + to add new device and click HP LaserJet 1018 printer name
- Click the Use drop-down menu and then click on Select Printer Software
- Search for 1022 in the search box and choose the HP LaserJet 1022 driver
- Finish installation and print test page

This allows to use old printer on macOS 10.14 and macOS 10.15 systems.

I hope it will help lots of people to save some gears.